# vue js get multiple values from inputs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So I have 2 blocks of HTML, each containing 2 input fields and when submitting the form, I want to get all values from the inputs, and then create an object from the values... 
As of know I've done it with plain vanilla JS and it works as it should, however if feels like to touching the DOM a bit to much, and also are very much depending on a specific DOM struckture, and therefore I was thinking there must be a better way, the VUE way so to speak, however im a bit stuck on how to do this the VUE way, which is why posting the question here in hope of getting some useful tips :)

HTML:

```
<form novalidate autocomplete="off">
  <div class="input-block-container">
    <div class="input-block">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Insert name" name="name[]" />
      <input-effects></input-effects>
    </div>
    <div class="input-block">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Insert email address" name="email[]" />
      <input-effects></input-effects>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-block-container">
    <div class="input-block">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Insert name" name="name[]" />
      <input-effects></input-effects>
    </div>
    <div class="input-block">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Insert email address" name="email[]" />
      <input-effects></input-effects>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="button button--primary" @click.prevent="sendInvites"><span>Send</span></button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
methods: {
    createDataObject() {

      let emailValues = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="email"]');

      emailValues.forEach((email) => {
        let name = email.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value;
          if(email.value !== "" && name !== "") {
            this.dataObj.push({
              email: email.value,
              name
            });
          }
      });

      return JSON.stringify(this.dataObj);

    },
    sendInvites() {
        const objectToSend = this.createDataObject();

        console.log(objectToSend);

        //TODO: Methods to send data to server


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide data properties for each of your inputs if you have static content.

```
data: function() {
   return {
      name1: '',
      email1: '',
      name2: '',
      email2: ''
   }
}
```

Then use them in your template:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Insert name" v-model="name1" />
```

Access in method by **this.name1**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div id="app">
   <h1> Finds </h1>
     <div v-for="find in finds">
       <input name="name[]" v-model="find.name">
       <input name="email[]" v-model="find.email">
     </div>
    <button @click="addFind">
      New Find
    </button>
  <pre>{{ $data | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

Vue Component

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    finds: []
  },
  methods: {

    addFind: function () {
      this.finds.push({ name: '', email: '' });
    }
    enter code here

  }
});
```